# How to create a formik form using class components?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want a generic form wrapper and generic field wrappers. I have these files:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import pComponent from "pComponent";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import { object, func, elementType, any, bool, oneOfType } from "prop-types";


export default class PL_Form extends Component {

  render() {
    let { children, onSubmit, initialValues, ...otherProps } = props;
    
    return (
      <Formik onSubmit={onSubmit} initialValues={initialValues} {...otherProps}>
        <Form>
          {children}
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    );
  }
}
```

and for Field

```
import React from "react";
import pComponent from "pComponent";
import { Field } from "formik";
import classNames from 'classnames';
import ValidationError from "./ValidationError";

export default class MyField extends pComponent {

    render() {
    let { name, fieldProps, component, className, fieldClassName, ...otherProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Field name={name} id={name} className={fieldClassName} {...otherProps}>
        {
          (props) => {
            const { field, form, meta } = props;
            return (
              <this.props.component 
                {...field}
                {...fieldProps}
                form={form}
                meta={meta}
                className={classNames(this.props.className, { invalid: meta.error && meta.touched })}
              >
                <ValidationError {...meta} />
              </this.props.component>
            );
          }
        }
      </Field>
    );
  }
}
```

And I would like them to be used like so:

```
import React from "react";
import MyForm from "./Form";
import MyTextField from "./TextField";

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.initialValues = {
      name: "",
      pw: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <MyForm onSubmit={console.log} initialValues={this.initialValues}>
      <MyTextField name="name"/>
      <MyTextField name="pw"/>
    </MyForm>;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Looking at the error origin inside the Formik lib, it appears `<Formik>` is a function component, which internally calls the `useRef` hook.
Does this mean that the entire hierarchy need to be function components? Everything I found uses function components, but my codebase is already pretty big...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. ReactDOM was not updated and did not support hooks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).